# clCreateBuffer() never fails

Tags: c++, c, memory, opencl, gpgpu

Intending to use ALL the available on-GPU memory for my algorithm, so retrieving it's amount with:

```
clGetDeviceInfo( ..., CL_DEVICE_GLOBAL_MEM_SIZE, ... );
```

which is **536543232** bytes, and then allocate it on GPU with:

```
clCreateBuffer( gpuContext, CL_MEM_READ_WRITE, 536543232, NULL, & errcode_ret );
```

Wondered why it worked and if it would fail if try to allocate some more memory? Tried out 100 gigs and it still worked!

```
clCreateBuffer( gpuContext, CL_MEM_READ_WRITE, 100000000000, NULL, & errcode_ret );
```

So the question is why it works with whatever amount of memory specified?

Comment: What are you getting when you check the value of `errcode_ret`? Normally functions like this will fail by setting a value in that variable, not by crashing the program or throwing an exception.

Comment: @Xirema errcode_ret is 0 after all of these calls which is CL_SUCCESS

Comment: Could you edit in a full program which reproduces this issue? A sample program on my computer produced the error code `-61`, which corresponds to `CL_INVALID_BUFFER_SIZE`.

Comment: @Xirema thank you for your attention. Problem actually "solved" now. I just proceeded at writing my first OpenCL app and discovered that upon enqueing the kernel which receives that buffer as parameter (passed with clSetKernelArg()) **pfn_notify()** invoked with CL_MEM_OBJECT_ALLOCATION_FAILURE error. Aquiring less memory at call to **clCreateBuffer()** solves the problem. I am trying all of these at my attic PC with OpenCL v1.1 and 12 years old GPU - I doubt you can reproduce that :)

Comment: @Xirema as I expected at the beginning, you actually **cannot** allocate CL_DEVICE_GLOBAL_MEM_SIZE amount of memory. Probably because some of that memory already used by something at Ubuntu_server? or is **constant/local**? etc. There is CL_DEVICE_MAX_MEM_ALLOC_SIZE, but, magically, it **does** allocate more than that with single call. Scouting the web now in search for answers to how allocate as much memory as possible.

Comment: `CL_DEVICE_MAX_MEM_ALLOC_SIZE` is the limit on individual buffers, and is required to be the larger of either 128Mb, or `CL_DEVICE_GLOBAL_MEM_SIZE / 4`. So in most real-world scenarios, you should assume you cannot allocate buffers taking up more than 25% of total device memory. [See the Specification on how `CL_DEVICE_MAX_MEM_ALLOC_SIZE` is defined](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenCL/sdk/2.0/docs/man/xhtml/clGetDeviceInfo.html). I don't know where you're observing that someone is allocating more than that, unless total memory is less than 512Mb.

Comment: I should emphasize that it's required to *at least be* the number I specified; Implementations are allowed to set the limit higher if the hardware can properly support it. I've seen very few sets of hardware that support more than 33% memory use in a single buffer, but it's possible that it has happened.

Comment: @Xirema I see, thank you. I guess, to allocate all the CL_DEVICE_GLOBAL_MEM_SIZE of GPU memory I need just create 4 buffers of CL_DEVICE_MAX_MEM_ALLOC_SIZE ... and pass 4 similar (but pointing to different buffers) params to kernel ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I may happen if OpenCL platform has lazy memory allocation (almost every platform does that). I guess some OpenCL platforms just check if what you requested can be allocated on `clCreateBuffer`, and maybe yours doesn't. You will probably get an error on the first OpenCL functions that actually uses your buffer, like `clEnqueueWriteBuffer()` etc. What is your OpenCL platform?

Comment: My OpenCL version is 1.1, NVIDIA 340 driver, Ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: Try to do a write to that 100GB buffer. It should fail. IIRC, also in other cases NVIDIA OpenCL platform sometimes tends to set error not in the actual failing function, but later, for example if `clEnqueueNDRangeKernel` call fails, error can be returned in the next `clFinish` or `clWaitForEvents` call (that's not related to lazy memory allocation).

Comment: **clEnqueueNDRangeKernel()** actually fails with **CL_MEM_OBJECT_ALLOCATION_FAILURE** error, yes, thank you. As I was expecting, it indeed fails even when I try allocate **CL_DEVICE_GLOBAL_MEM_SIZE** memory, due to some limit per single allocation. Have to somehow allocate the whole global memory with several calls to **clCreateBuffer()**, sigh ...